# How to automatically register helpers class in ServiceProvider?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a Laravel 5.1 project and have developed a lot of helpers.

Is there any way to automatically register the helpers class in ServiceProivder instead of adding them manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have worked on it and I finally fixed it by putting different puzzles together ending with this solution:

**For Laravel 5:**

**Step 1.** Created folder `app/Helpers`

**Step 2.** In `app/Providers` folder, create provider `HelpersServiceProvider.php` using following artisan command:

```
php artisan make:provider HelpersServiceProvider
```

**Step 3.** In `HelpersServiceProvider.php` file, we make a `foreach loop` inside register function to fetch all helpers classes like this:

```
public function register()
{
    foreach (glob(app_path() . '/Helpers/*.php') as $helpersfilename)
    {
        require_once($helpersfilename);
    }
}
```

**Step 4.** In `config/app.php` added following line

```
/*
* Application Service Providers added by developer...
*/
App\Providers\HelpersServiceProvider::class,
```

That is it, the solution here is tested and works on all versions of Laravel 5.x. Now you can add unlimited helpers in helpers folder, they will be automatically added to the system.

**Laravel 4** is not tested yet, but if some body do it, please add/edit this for Laravel 4.

Comment: A very good solution. However, in my case I am adding the helpers directly to the `autoload` inside `composer.json`. This is how I have it: `"files": [            "app/Helpers/xyz.php"]` I found that easier since I will only be having 1 or 2 helper files in my application. But I will definitely use your method if I am gonna have many helper files.

Comment: I do fully agree, some time having such method helping to the job automatically in stead of forgetting even with so few files, but again.

Comment: true.. good point. Your method is a one time job and all future helpers will be included automatically. I like it.

Comment: I like this approach. But, its stated in the docs that `within the register method, you should only bind things into the service container. You should never attempt to register any event listeners, routes, or any other piece of functionality within the register method`. So, I'm wondering if this approach counts as 'binding something into the service container' or if it goes against what is stated in the docs? I'm just trying to understand things better here to make my our decision, but again, I like this approach!

Comment: @cbcaio i am not aware of it, I will investigate that and come back with answer if you still need to clarify this

Comment: but if you want to use Helper::function in a controller you will need to code "use Helper;". How can you avoid that?