# send id_user of choosed user to database

Tags: php

here is name and informations of my users:

> this is my code:

```
  <?php
$id=$fgmembersite->UserID(); 

/* echo "$id"; */


$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name= 'site';
$db_table= 'tablesite';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';


$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");
$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET  utf8");

$dbresult=mysql_query("SELECT tablesite.id_user,
                              tablesite.name,
                              tablesite.family,
                              tablesite.username,
                              tablesite.phone_number,
                              tablesite.email
                       FROM  $db_table",$con);
   $i = 1;

                       while($amch=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))

{?>
  <?php

echo "<form name=f1 id='form_$i' method='post' action=submit_action.php accept-charset='UTF-8'>\r\n";
echo'<div dir="rtl">';
echo "نام خدمت دهنده: "."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp".$amch["name"]." ".$amch["family"]."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"."شماره تماس: ".$amch["phone_number"]."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"."ایمیل: ".$amch["email"].'<br>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="' . $amch["id_user"] . '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="name" value="' . $amch["name"] . '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="family" value="' . $amch["family"] . '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="phone_number" value="' . $amch["phone_number"] . '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="email" value="' . $amch["email"] . '">';
echo '<input type="submit" name="choose" value="انتخاب مشتری"/>';echo'<hr/>';
echo'<hr/>';
echo'</div>';
echo "</form>\r\n";
    $i++;
}
?>
```

> for example i choosed one buddy that you can see in below picture, from appeared list:

[image]

and his information sends to second page:

[image: second page]

all things property works till this step. in next step i want to send id_user of selected user. as you see in picture, id_user of current user is 34.
bellow code is all codes of second page.

problem is where i want id_user (for this user 34) to database but i get following notice:

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: id_user in C:\wamp\www\source\submit_action.php on line 339
>
> line 339: VALUES ('$id',
>                    '" . $_POST['id_user'] . "', etc...

```
        <form name="form5" method="post" action="" >


<div dir="rtl"> 

                    <?php


$username=$fgmembersite->UserNameOfUser();
   $db_host = 'localhost';
   $db_name= 'site';
   $db_table= 'job_list';
   $db_user = 'root';
   $db_pass = '';



$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");
$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET  utf8");

$dbresult=mysql_query("SELECT job_list.job_id,
                              job_list.job_name,
                              tablesite.username
                       FROM  $db_table
                       INNER JOIN relation
                       on job_list.job_id=relation.job_id
                       INNER JOIN tablesite
                       on relation.user_id=tablesite.id_user AND tablesite.username='$username'",$con);
echo'* خدمتی که ارائه داده اید: ','<br/>';                     
echo '<select name="job" dir="rtl">';

while($amch=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))
{ 
   echo '<option value="'.$amch['job_id'].'">'.$amch['job_name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>'; ?><br/>
</div>      

<div dir="rtl"> 


            <label for='date' >* تاریخ عملیات:</label><br/>
            <?php

echo'<select dir="rtl" name="day">';
for($day=1;$day<=31;$day++)
            {


            echo '<option value="' . $day . '">' . $day . '</option>';

            }
echo'</select>';


echo'<select dir="rtl" name="month">';
for($month=1;$month<=12;$month++)
            {


            echo '<option value="' . $month . '">' . $month . '</option>';

            }
echo'</select>';

            echo'<select dir="rtl" name="year">';
            for($year=1388;$year<=1410;$year++)
            { 
            echo '<option value="' . $year . '">' . $year . '</option>';

            } 

echo'</select>';

?>          


            <br/>
            <label for='price' >* هزینه کار:</label><br/>
            <input type='text'  dir="rtl" name='price' id='price' value='' maxlength="50" placeholder="54000"/>تومان<br/>

        <label for='textaria' >توضیحات:</label><br/>
        <textarea name="textaria" cols="" rows=""></textarea><br/>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="ثبت عملیات" />

</div>


            <?php
if(isset($_POST['choose']))
{
$id_user =$_POST['id_user'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$family=$_POST['family'];
$phone_number=$_POST['phone_number'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
echo "$name", " " , "$family", '<br/>' , "$phone_number", '<br/>' , "$email",'<br/>' , "$id_user";
}

?>  

</form>



<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
$date = $_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day'];

$id=$fgmembersite->UserID(); 

$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name= 'site';
$db_table= 'action';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';


$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $con);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $con);
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = 'utf8'", $con);


$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
 $ins = "INSERT INTO $db_table
         (service_provider_id,customer_id,date,price,job_id,service_provider_comment)
         VALUES ('$id',
                 '" . $_POST['id_user'] . "',
                 '$date',
                 '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['price']) . "',
                 '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['job']) . "',
                 '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['textaria']) . "')";
$saved=mysql_query($ins );
mysql_close($con); 

/*echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("عملیات با موفقیت ثبت شد")';
echo '</script>';
echo '<script>window.location.href = "choose_user.php";</script>';
*/

}
?>
```

> after if(isset($_POST['submit'])), cant recognize $id_user. i think problem is here.

Comment: MySQL extension is officially deprecated (Removed in PHP 7.)
And, I can't find any field named "id_user" in your form, so that's probably why it isn't sent via POST

Comment: @sajad I am looking at your issue

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ many thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have more than one form and if you do not forward your value to second form, the value will be flushed (become `NULL`, said in other words it does not re-send the `id_user` automatically to a second form).

First of all you need to declare and retrieve the `id_user` on your new form, by adding following line in the beginning of your `submit_action.php` file:

```
$id_user = $_POST['id_user'];
```

So your code will look like this:

```
.....
<div dir="rtl">

    <?php
    $id_user = $_POST['id_user'];

    $username = $fgmembersite->UserNameOfUser();
etc....
```

Here next you can either pass the variable inside a hidden input, by adding following line before your form submit button so it looks like this:

```
.....
<input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="<?php echo $id_user ?>">

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="ثبت عملیات"/>

etc....
```

Or you can pass the variable directly in your statement so it looks like this:

```
.....
VALUES ('$id',
                 '" . $id_user . "',
                 '$date',
                 '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['price']) . "',
etc....
```

That should solve the trick.

**Note:** After chatting with OP the answer is updated and further improved.

Comment: where to put first solution?

<input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="<?php $_POST['id_user'] ?>>

Comment: need to delete anything or just put that?

Comment: No you do not need to delete any thing for first solution, the first line just put it inside `submit_action.php` before `<input name="submit" type="submit" value="ثبت عملیات"/>` by the way I have edit the code I missed a double qoute so it should be `<input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="<?php $_POST['id_user'] ?>">`

Comment: i used this, no more notice, but nothing sends :(

Comment: this must be another issue, I will look at it and see if I can figure some thing with submission part, let you know soon possible. If you fix it mean while let me also know

Comment: did you found anything bro?

Comment: so far it looks fine, maybe i have over seen details but what was the problem exactly with the submission part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95173/discussion-between-sajad-and-maytham-mahiam).

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['id_user']  is unknown, because it doesn't send with the second form. it means id_user don't send to the block: if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {...} so it is Undefined index.