# Helpers in Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with helpers  , I create correctly the helper and I can call this helper that I created in view but when I need to access to property.

```
{{Text::showBanner()}};
```

The function of helperI created called showBanner

```
 public static function showBanner() {
        $banner= Banner::all();

        return $banner;
    }
```

How can I access to attribute id of $banner ?

**UPDATED**

When I use this

```
  @foreach ( $banners as $item)
                        {{$item}}
                       @endforeach
```

I need to change this $banner for this helper

Comment: `Banner::all()` gives you *all* banners. A collection and not a single model. That's probably the problem here.

Comment: Yes , I know , how can I put this Text::showBanner in a function Helper @lukasgeiter

Comment: @jcsa look at this pls and let me know if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665553/how-to-automatically-register-helpers-class-in-serviceprovider/31665919#31665919

Comment: Yes all of their answers helps to me , but my problem is when i try to use the {{Text::showBanner()}} in the foreach replacing the variable $banners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a file app/helpers.php with your desired code:

```
    function showBanner() {
        $banner = Banner::all();
        return $banner;
    }
```

Autoload it with composer

```
    {
        "autoload": {
            "files": [
                "app/helpers.php"
            ]
        }
    }
```

use it {{ showBanner() }}

Comment: I can use , I updated the question with problem @tudor

Comment: $item is an instance of Banner entity. You can it in blade templating engine like you use it in php. You can call methods on it {{ $item->getLink() }} or access public properties.

Comment: Yes I know  but I need to use the Helper function in thi foreach  @tudor

Comment: you can do this but it is a wrong way to do it: @foreach(Text::showBanner() as $item) { // your code here}