# Composer file autoloading not working - Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

Ive created a helper file which i am trying to autoload in my composer.json see composer below:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*",
    "zurb/foundation": "5.4.*",
    "caffeinated/presenter": "~2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "4.0",
    "guzzlehttp/oauth-subscriber": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Project/Helpers/Helpers.php"
    ],
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Project\\": "app/Project"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
}
```

After a composer install and dumpautoload this works completely fine on my local environment but when i push to production i get an undefinded function error (function is located in my helpers.php)

Ive composer installed/dumpautoload on my server but still now luck. Any ideas?

Comment: if you want to includ helpers I suggest you to follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665553/how-to-automatically-register-helpers-class-in-serviceprovider/31665919#31665919 and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use `composer update`. This solved the problem for laravel 5.2.